# Iteratively adding matrices and elapsed time in a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have here a function, `generate.board(n, p)` that generates a matrix of n rows and n columns (parameter `p` is not important here).

I've also created an empty list `trials` to store my output in.

What I want to do:

I would like to iteratively run `generate.board` 10 times for each value of `n` from `10` to `100` with spacing of `10`. Also, for each run of `generate.board`, I would like to record the elapsed time.

I would like help with storing the matrixes and elapsed time inside trials. I'll show you what I have here, which throws an error:

`subscript out of bounds`

My code:

```
trials <- list()
for (ii in seq(10, 100, by= 10)) {
  for (jj in seq(10)) {
    trials[[ii]][jj] <- generate.board(n = ii, p = 0.4)
    trials[ii / 10][jj + 1] <- system.time(generate.board(n = ii, p = 0.4))[3]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further modification, we simply use `paste` to name our list entries. Your error occurs because there is no list item #10 to which you want to assign the first matrix.

```
trials <- list()
for (ii in seq(10, 100, by= 10)) {
  for (jj in seq(10)) {
    trials[[paste(ii)]][jj] <- generate.board(n = ii, p = 0.4)
    attributes(trials[[paste(ii)]][jj]) <- list("Time" = system.time(generate.board(n = ii, p = 0.4))[3])
  }
}
```

Depending on what you need this for there are easier ways to do so. For starters you could use `system.time(rials[[paste(ii)]][jj] <- generate.board())`. You could also do it with a nested `lapply`. Then you don't have to manage indices yourself. Also checkout the function `microbenchmark::microbenchmark`.